# How to concatenate the text from ctl file vertically to horizontally and then save in a new ctl file using python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have a mlt.ctl file in which the text is arranged like this:

```
 znrmi_001/znrmi_001_001
 znrmi_001/znrmi_001_002
 znrmi_001/znrmi_001_003
 zntoy_001/zntoy_001_001
 zntoy_001/zntoy_001_002
 zntoy_001/zntoy_001_003
 zntoy_001/zntoy_001_004
 .......................
 zntoy_001/zntoy_001_160
 ....................
 zntoy_002/zntoy_002_001
 zntoy_002/zntoy_002_002
 .......................
 zntoy_002/zntoy_002_149
```

Need to save the desired format in the newmlt.ctl file, the desired format is shown below:

```
 znrmi_001 znrmi_001_001 znrmi_001_002 znrmi_001_003
 zntoy_001 zntoy_001_001 zntoy_001_002..................zntoy_001_160
 zntoy_002 zntoy_002_001 zntoy_002_002..................zntoy_002_149
 ....................................................................
```

I am trying hard in python, but getting the errors everytime.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fi= open("mlt.ctl","r")
y_list = []
for line in fi.readlines():
    a1 = line[0:9]
    a2 = line[10:19]
    a3 = line[20:23]
    if a3 in xrange(1,500):
       y = a1+ " ".join(line[20:23].split())
       print(y)
    elif int(a3) < 2:
       fo.write(lines+ "\n")
    else:
       stop
    y_list.append(y)
    print(y)
fi.close()
fo = open ("newmlt.ctl", "w")
for lines in y_list:
    fo.write(lines+ "\n")
fo.close()
```

I am getting elif error and code is not running properly, kindly provide the inputs.

Comment: What code have you already tried

Comment: @  Nikolay Shmyrev , kindly provide the inputs in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using regular expressions and saving the matches to a dictionary:

```
import re

REGEX = r"\d.\s(\S+)/(\S+)" # group 1: the unique index; group 2: the value
finder = re.compile(REGEX) # compile the regular expression

with open('mlt.ctl', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read() # read the entire file into data

matches = re.finditer(finder, data) # find all matches (one for each line)

d = {}
indices = []
for match in matches: # loop through the matches
    key = match.group(1) # the index
    val = match.group(2) # the value

    if key in d.keys(): # the key has already been processed, just append the value to the list
        d[key].append(val)
    else: # the key is new; create a new dict entry and keep track of the index in the indices list
        d[key] = [val]
        indices.append(key)


with open("newmlt.ctl", "w") as out:
    for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
        vals = " ".join(d[idx]) # join the values into a space-delimited string
        to_string = "{} {}\n".format(idx,vals)
        out.write(to_string)
```

Comment: It gives correct output, but it also gives serial number which starts from zero. like     0 znrmi_001 znrmi_001_001 znrmi_001_002 znrmi_001_003 , how to remove the serial number at the intial of the string.

Comment: I edited the answer. You just modify the `to_string` line to `to_string = "{} {}\n".format(idx,vals)` so that it no longer shows the index at the start.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 28, in <module>
    to_string = "{}. {} {}\n".format(idx,vals) IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: the correct code is in the answer. please take a look at [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

a little more pythonic:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('mlt.ctl') as f:
    for line in f:
        grp, val = line.strip().split('/')
        d[grp].append(val)
with open('newmlt.ctl','w') as f: 
    for k in sorted(d):
        oline = ' '.join([k]+d[k])+'\n'
        f.write(oline)
```

Comment: Working, but changes the order.

Comment: @Andy thought the file was sorted. if you want to preserve the key order prepare a list `keys=[]` and collect them in the input loop `if grp not in keys: keys.append(grp)`. in the output loop iterate over the keys `for k in keys:`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not related, but it seems you forget a ')' on line 11

```
 y = a1+ " ".join(line[20:23].split()
```

should be

```
 y = a1+ " ".join(line[20:23].split())
```

and the ':' at the `else` at line 14 and at the `for` at line 20

Also at line 12 you will probably compare a string and an integer